# Dreamweaver CS 5.5 ver 11.5 Built 5315 damages the document. How to solve it?

Tags: ide, dreamweaver

I have downloaded Dreamweaver CS5.5 version 11.5 Built 5315. It seems to be the newest one.

But the problem is that it changes the view of the document window. It looks like usual windows-style window (please see the screenshot). Before this version I used CS5 ver 11.0 Built 4909 and document window had normal view and style, just the same as whole Dreamweaver – it was grey with small text in title and small icons on the top right corner, just usual like it has to be.

But more than that, it behaves strange way when you resize that document window. It breaks long lines of code to the new line when you make document window smaller instead of just hiding it under the right side like in previous version.

What can it be? Is it possible to turn it to normal view and behavior? Has anyone had such problem? Please, help to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about the window styling, I always work with maximized document windows, so I don't know if this was a change, or there is something specific with your system.

Dreamweaver's default is to use word wrap in code view, this has been the case for many versions of Dreamweaver, if your older version wasn't using word wrap then that is something that you turned off. You can turn that off from View -> Code view options -> Word Wrap, or via the Word Wrap button in the code toolbar (along right side of your document window) in your screenshot it appears to be the bottom activated button it has an arrow on that starts on the bottom right of the icon and point to the left.